# How to draw hidden rib in Autodesk Inventor

Tags: modeling, cad, technical-drawing, autodesk-inventor

I drew the outer hollowed body and the cylinder on 2 separate parts but I can't figure out how to draw this rib so that it is passes through the centre of the cylinder, a video of a similar example would help a lot[image]

[image]

Here is my work so far [image]

[image]

Comment: It would be very easy if you have created the part with the A-A line on the  XZ plane. Have you? Show a screengrab of your work so far.

Comment: @Transistor Ok take a relook , should I make the rib in a separate part or what ?

Comment: You didn't answer my question regarding the XZ plane. It looks like the part is symmetrical about the YZ plane. It is important to read the comments carefully and try to answer all the questions asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It looks like the part is symmetrical about the YZ plane.
2. Create a new sketch on the YZ plane and draw the rib. Extrude it symmetrically. You may need to work in wireframe or "show hidden edges" (or whatever SolidWorks calls that).
3. No, you wouldn't create a separate part. The piece is all one.
4. I have no idea why you posted a picture of a cylinder.

[image]

*Figure 1. One way of creating the part is to draw half of it and mirror when complete. Screengrab from [OnShape](https://onshape.com) model.*

Comment: Ok I made big progress but when I try making the rib a error pops up check this new question i made about the error https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49038/autodesk-inventor-create-rib-feature-failed