# Autodesk inventor create rib feature failed

Tags: modeling, cad, technical-drawing, autodesk-inventor

It's been kind of painful to create a rib I'm new to inventor while I was trying to create a rib symmetric about the YZ Plane this error keeps popping up[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in my answer to your [previous question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49023/how-to-draw-hidden-rib-in-autodesk-inventor/49036?noredirect=1#comment90482_49036) you just need to create a closed loop sketch on that plane and extrude it 5 mm (or 10 mm symmetrically). There's no need for use of the rib tool.